# Read from and append to file at the same time while preserving end-of-line

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Conceptually I have an easy task... I have [loosely] structured data in a file:

```
Testing: debug, default CXXFLAGS
<100's of additional output lines>
Testing: release, default CXXFLAGS
<100's of additional output lines>
...
```

I try to summarize it in a log file:

```
echo "Configurations tested:" | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
echo $($GREP 'Testing: ' "$TEST_RESULTS" | $SED 's/Testing: /    * /g') | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
```

Instead of:

```
Configurations tested:
    * debug, default CXXFLAGS
    * release, default CXXFLAGS
```

I get:

```
Configurations tested:
1 3way.cpp 3way.h CMakeLists.txt CMakeLists.txt.diff Doxyfile Filelist.txt GNUmakefile
GNUmakefile-cross Install.txt License.txt Readme.txt TestData TestVectors adhoc.cpp.proto
adler32.cpp adler32.h aes.h algebra.cpp algebra.h ...
```

I think I am wreaking havoc on the file buffer `$TEST_RESULTS` because its being read from in the `grep`, and written to with the `tee`.

When I attempt to put the result of `$GREP 'Testing: ' "$TEST_RESULTS" | $SED 's/Testing: /    * /g'` in a shell variable, I loose the line endings which results in one big concatenation:

```
* debug, default CXXFLAGS    * release, default CXXFLAGS ... <30 additional configs>
```

How do I read from and append to a file at the same time while preserving the end-of-lines?

---

I've made some progress with:

```
ESCAPED=$($GREP 'Testing: ' "$TEST_RESULTS" | $AWK -F ": " '{print "  -" $2 "$"}')
echo $ESCAPED | tr $ '\n' | tee -a "$TEST_RESULTS"
```

However, it can't use `*` as a bullet point, and it seems to drop leading space:

```
Configurations tested:
-debug, default CXXFLAGS
 -release, default CXXFLAGS
```

I'm not using `sed` because swapping-in a new line is an absolute pain across platforms. Platforms include BSD, Cygwin, Linux, OS X, Solaris.

Comment: [The problem with `*` and spaces is that you left out the double quotes around variable substitutions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$TEST_RESULTS` is the name of a file that contains the test output. If I understand correctly, you want to append the list of tested configurations to that same file.

So, use a temporary file. Then append that file to the original.

```bash
tmpfile="$( mktemp )"
{
    echo "Configurations tested:"
    sed -ne 's/^Testing: \(.*\)/  * \1/p' -- "$TEST_RESULTS"
} >"$tmpfile"

cat <"$tmpfile" >>"$TEST_RESULTS"
rm -f -- "$tmpfile"
```

If you don't have `mktemp`, you could use

```
tmpfile="$TEST_RESULTS.tmp"
```

or

```
tmpfile=~/tmp/"$(basename -- "$TEST_RESULTS").tmp"
```

or something similar... assuming that file doesn't already exist (in which case it (or the file it points to for symlinks) will be overwritten and then removed). In any case, avoid world-writeable directories for writing temporary files with fixed names as that's bad practice from a security standpoint.

---

On systems where `sponge` is available:

```bash
{
    echo "Configurations tested:"
    sed -ne 's/^Testing: \(.*\)/  * \1/p' -- "$TEST_RESULTS"
} | sponge -a -- "$TEST_RESULTS"
```

Here, `sponge -a` will append the output of the preceding compound command (`{ ...; }`) to the given output file.  The `sponge` utility will write the output to a temporary location and will then replace the named file with that.  The effect of the `-a` option is that the output is appended to, rather than overwriting, the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that your forgot to quote `$(echo...)` and `$ESCAPED` therefore invoking the split+glob operator, where the expansion is split according to characters of `$IFS` and the resulting words subject to globbing (`*` for instance expanded to the list of non-hidden filenames in the current directory), a misfeature common to most Bourne-like shells.

```
# get a $PATH where to find standard utilities rather having to hardcode
# the path of each (you also forgot the quotes around those `$SED`/`$GREP`...)
PATH=$(command -p getconf PATH)${PATH:+:$PATH}
export PATH

printf '%s\n' 'Configurations tested:' \
              "$(sed -ne 's/^Testing: \(.*\)/  * \1/p' -- "$TEST_RESULTS")" |
  tee -a -- "$TEST_RESULTS"
```

(also remember you can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data).

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
awk -v pattern="Testing:" '$0 ~ pattern { sub(pattern, "  *"); print }'
```

This should work with any version of `sed`, since it contains no obvious extensions. It is not necessary to handle the newlines explicitly as long as you take care to quote your variables properly, in order to prevent word splitting.

Comment: *"Frankly, I don't see why you are messing around with the newlines...."* - I told you why: *"When I attempt to put the result of `<command above>` in a shell variable, I loose the line endings which results in one big concatenation"*.

Comment: Well, if you don't want the shell to do its thing, then use quotes. `echo $var` is not the same as `echo "$var"`.

Comment: Thanks. *" if you don't want the shell to do its thing, then use quotes"* - OK, could you provide it in your answer? Also, does your Awk work everywhere? I try to avoid Sed because of the different behavior on BSDs, Linux, OS X, Solaris and Unix. Its been my experience that Awk can be a pain point too.